# Can build with tsc but not on the fly with ts-node

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc, ts-node

I am creating my first Node.js module to publish it on NPM. [This](https://itnext.io/step-by-step-building-and-publishing-an-npm-typescript-package-44fe7164964c) tutorial shows how to do it with TypeScript. The complete sample only uses the script `"build": "tsc"` to compile the code and works ok.

This is the tutorial structure (I exclude tests folder and formatting config files because they are not relevant here):

```
- my-awesome-greeter/ <--- the name of the package
  - src/
    - index.ts <--- entry point
  - package.json
  - tsconfig.json
  - lib/ <--- output of "npm run build"
    - index.js
    - index.d.ts
```

Both `build` and `dev` scripts work OK at this point.

Then I add my own custom types creating a new `typings/` directory at the same level as `src/` (I followed [this](https://dev.to/danywalls/how-to-create-your-own-typings-14l6) other tutorial):

```
  - typings/
    - my-awesome-greeter/
      - index.d.ts (2)
    - index.d.ts (1)
```

(1) only contains:

```
/// <reference path="my-awesome-greeter/index.d.ts" />
```

(2) contains the custom typings:

```
declare module "my-awesome-greeter" {
    interface Person {
        name: string;
        age: number;
        country: string;
    }
}
```

##### Problem now

`build` script works OK, but `dev` script fails with the following error:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/index.ts:1:24 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'my-awesome-greeter' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { Person } from "my-awesome-greeter";
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    at createTSError (C:\Users\localUser\Documents\Projects\my-awesome-greeter\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:859:12)
```

`src/index.ts` contains:

```
import { Person } from "my-awesome-greeter";

export const PersonGreeter = (person: Person) => `Hello ${person.name} with age ${person.age} from ${person.country}`
```

What am I doing wrong?